Unable to execute commands from the powershell terminal inside VSCode but they execute fine in powershell in the same directory
The PowerShell terminal inside VS code doesn't execute commands related to Git, Ruby, Seedling, and Ruby. But the PowerShell terminal in the same directory executes these commands correctly.

PowerShell in VScode vs PowerShell
I have already added all the paths to the PATH in both the user and system variables. I have run VSCode as an administrator but still the issue persists.

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.
